# Align items in same row boot

Tags: css

I've been trying to show items on the same line in bootstrap here is my code, it's was working before , but i think i messed it up , i'm kinda new to bootstrap, any help would be much appreciated.

```
    <div class="row">
        {% for album in all_albums %}

             <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-2">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}">
                            <img src="{{ album.album_logo.url }}" class="img-responsive">
                         </a>
                        <div class="caption">
                            <h2>{{ album.album_title}}</h2>
                            <h4>{{ album.artist}}</h4>

                        <!-- Details -->
                            <a href="{% url 'music:detail' album.id %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Details</a>
                        <!-- Delete -->
                            <form action="{% url 'music:album-delete' album.id %}" method="post" style="display: inline;">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="album_id" value="{{ album.id}} "/>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> Delete
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        <!--Favorite-->
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-favorite">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star">{% if album.is_favorite%}active{% endif %}</span>
                             </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? What's not working?

Comment: Albums are displayed each one in new row while i want them on the same row like 3 each row how to do that